# How would I build a Discord bot that reacts with a series of custom emojis when one or more keywords is present in a post?

Tags: reactjs, bots, discord, emoji

I run a Star Trek server, one of many, and I wish to have a bot that would react to posts containing the words "tribble" or "tribble" with a series of custom tribble emojis in order. The emojis feature a single tribble, three tribbles, five tribbles, and a mirror universe tribble with fangs.

I am at the middle of this search and haven't found an existing bot that will do what I'm looking for.

Comment: pick ANY language your familiar with. Find a discord bot framework. Theres a lot of them that allow for making a bot to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (message.content == 'tribble') {
 message.react('');
}
```

But you might want to restrict that a bit as users tend to abuse such things. If you need to use custom emojis you will have to use the Emoji ID which you can see when you post the emoji like this

```
\:tribble:
```

This will put out the emoji + its ID for message.react('1234567890');